# Nigerian time using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show Nigerian time on my asp.net MVC 3 website. Do I need to change culture ?

currently, I am using like this:

```
@Model.ReportDate.ToString("hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
CultureInfo igNG = new CultureInfo("ig-NG"); //change according to specific Nigerian culture
@Model.ReportDate.ToString("c", igNG); //change 'c' to whatever format you want
```

`CultureInvariant` isn't associated with any particular country or region, just based on the English language.